# How to populate NA for blank columns if one of the corresponding duplicate column has values in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, fillna

The following input dataset has duplicate values in column 'Name' and one of them has corresponding value in column 'rank'. I want to fill the other duplicate blank columns as 'NA'. The dataset is large so I can't use find and replace option.

```
INPUT

| NAME | RANK | 
| A    |  
| A    |  1
| B    |  
| B    | 
| C    |  2
| C    | 
| C    |  
| D    |  3
| D    |  4

OUTPUT

| NAME | RANK |
| A    |  NA 
| A    |  1
| B    |  NA
| B    |  NA
| C    |  2
| C    |  NA
| C    |  NA
| D    |  3
| D    |  4
```

Comment: Look into Powerquery

Comment: I assume your data starts at A1, =IF(A1:B10="","NA",A1:B10) will change every empty cell to NA

Comment: Why not use Autofilter to filter for blank values and paste NA in the filtered rows?

Comment: You can also select the range and press keyboard key F5 and then `Special Cells >> Blank` and populate with `NA`.

Comment: The easiest way I believe given by @shrivallabha.redij